# Компьютерная игра python

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, инспекция-кода

Решаю задачи на питоне, столкнулся с такой вот интересной, хотелось бы увидеть что да как решают другие

какие есть предложения, как улучшить можно, что исправить?

Василий, любит играть в компьютерные игры, помогите ему выиграть, в следующей игре:
Герой компьютерной игры, обладающий силой в 25 баллов, находится в круглом зале, из которого ведут 10 закрытых дверей. За каждой дверью героя ждет либо магический артефакт, дарующий силу от 10 до 80 баллов, либо монстр, имеющий силу от 5 до 100 баллов, с которым герою нужно сразиться. Битву выигрывает персонаж, обладающий наибольшей силой; если силы равны, побеждает герой.
Напишите программу, помогающую Василию определить:

1. За сколькими дверями героя ждет смерть.
2. Вывести номера дверей в том порядке, в котором следует их открывать герою, чтобы остаться в живых, если такое возможно.
   Пояснение:
   •   Информацию о том, что находится за дверями заполнить, используя генератор случайных чисел.
   •   Вывести эту самую информацию на экран в понятном табличном виде.

````
hero = 25
upgrade, Monsters, doors = [], [], {}
monsterORartefact = ['monster', 'artefact']
for i in range(1, 11):
    doors[i] = choice(monsterORartefact)
    if doors[i] == 'monster':

        doors[i] = 'monster' + ' (' + str(randint(5,100)) + ')'
    elif doors[i] == 'artefact':
        doors[i] = 'artefact' + ' (' + str(randint(10,80)) + ')'
for i in range(1, 11):
    if doors[i][0] == 'm':
        if int(doors[i][9:11]) > hero:
            print('За дверью: ' + str(i) + ' - ждет смерть (' + str(doors[i][9:11]) + ')')  # если за дверью монстр
            Monsters.append(i)
        elif int(doors[i][9:11]) <= hero:
            print('За дверью: ' + str(i) + ' - слабый монстр (' + str(doors[i][9:11]) + ')')
            Monsters.append(i)
    elif doors[i][0] == 'a':  # если за дверью артефакт
        upgrade.append(i)
        print('За дверью: ' + str(i) + ' - артефакт! (' + str(doors[i][10:12]) + ')')
print('Главный герой: Мне следует набраться сил...')
for i in upgrade:
    hero += int(doors[i][10:12])
    print('[+] UPGRADE!! [+] Моя сила равна: ' + str(hero) + ' (дверь:' + str(i) + ')' )
print('Главный герой: Иду убивать монстров, им не победить меня!')
for i in Monsters:
    if int(doors[Monsters[0]][9:11]) < hero:
        print('Монстр за дверью: ' + str(i) + ' - убит...')  
    else:
        print('Я не могу его убить.. я останусь тут навсегда')
        break       

print(doors)
input('Нажмите любую клавишу') ```
````

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Ну то есть программа может смотреть что там сгенерилось и сообщает на этой основе герою инфу? А так да - решайте, поможем )

Comment: отправил решение, что думаете, как улучшить можно?

Comment: у вас есть типовые объекты, почему вы не используете ООП для решения? Класс дверь, в которой могут объекты классов артефактов и монстров. Класс для самого героя я бы тоже создал. Прописать методы для всех возможных ситуаций, да, и все. В `main` прописать основную логику

Answer (score 0):

Пример реализации, как я это вижу. Достаточно подробно все постарался описать, как организовать и использовать методы и классы. Это пример, но не готовое решение. Я покажу как использовать, но логику составьте самостоятельно.

```py
from random import randint as ri
from random import choice as ch

# класс дверь, при инициализации добавляем 
# instance - имеется в виду либо артефакт, либо монстр
class Door:
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

# в данный класс мы передаем героя с его здоровьем
# и в зависимости от того что за дверью получаем результат его здоровья
    def openDoor(self, hero):
        if isinstance(self.instance, Artefact):
            hero.health += self.instance.force
        else:
            hero.health -= self.instance.damage

# что мы будем возвращить когда вызовем str() для объекта класса
    def __str__(self):
        return "Что за дверью: " + str(self.instance)

# класс для артефакта, ri это ранодмный Int в диапазоне
# см. import
# force - это сила, которая будет плюсоваться к силе героя
class Artefact:
    def __init__(self):
        self.force = ri(10,80)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Artefact with " + str(self.force) 

# класс для монстра, если все комментарии прочитаны, то тут будет ясно
class Monster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.damage = ri(5,100)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Monster with " + str(self.damage) + " damage"


class Hero:
    def __init__(self, health):
        self.health = health

    def __str__(self):
        return "Здоровье героя:" + str(self.health)

# создание игрового поля с дверьми
doorSet = {}
for i in range(10):
    instances = [Artefact(), Monster()]
    doorSet[i] = Door(ch(instances)) # см. import вверху что такое ch

# в переменной doorSet у нас набор с различными дверьми
# создадим героя c 25 hp
hero = Hero(25)
```

Теперь герой создан, попробуем открыть дверь и посмотреть, что случиться со здоровьем:

```
# пример открытия двери
doorSet[0].openDoor(hero)
print(hero)

>>Здоровье героя:45
```

Все работает. Пару слов про основную логику. Я вижу так что необходимо написать метод для просмотра дверей без их открытия, т. е. не привязаное никак к здоровью героя и сравнивать со здоровьем героя. Как это будет выглядеть вам решать.

Т. е. на данный момент у нас есть набор с дверьми за которыми находятся некие объекты. Как их открывать? Найти самого маленького монстра, далее сравнить со здоровьем и если уходит в минус, то искать артефакт и т.д. Проверку на смерть героя можно положить в тот же метод `openDoor`, а в самомо классе героя добавить поле "alive" с логическим значением , например. Пишите классы и методы, а в основной логике создавайте объекты и манипулируйте ими с помощью методов.

Comment: Дмитрий, благодарю за столь подробное решение и альтернативное видение задачи! 
Не использовал ООП, т.к еще не изучал, только начал учить python, использовал лишь базовые его возможности - теперь же вижу как это упрощает задачи, буду учиться.

Comment: пожалуйста, здесь не все решение + это только база ООП. Успехов в обучении